# How do I fix the flaws of my red normal map channel?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, normal-map

It's me again and I need your help. Lately,I've been creating my own FNaF textures from scratch and yesterday,I noticed that the normals had these strange spots. I checked the normal map with the standard RGBA view and everything appeared to be doing well,but when I checked the red channel,there were these weird splotches that looked just like the flaws I saw in the material viewport. How do I fix these flaws?

**Normal Map:**

[image]

**Red Channel:**

[image]

**Edit:** 
I think I know what was wrong. I inverted the wrong channel. If I'm correct,please notify me.

[image]

Comment: Did you bake this normal map in Blender? Can you please upload the file you made for baking?

Comment: Sadly,I can't. I'm using my school laptop and they blocked the ability for me to attach .blend files.

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of the setup and describe how you do it?

Comment: I just posted the baking setup.

Comment: Did you bake the map in Blender? If you want to bake DirectX normal map then invert Y channel not X. Did you try to invert red channel back and see how it works?

Comment: Yes,I did and it still had those strange lines.